# OpenCV face detection - if statement

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using OpenCV to detect face in c++. this code works well, but I want to Add new function that if the code can't find a face. so I'll use if-else statement. but I don't know how use that. What should go into the if statement conditions? Thanks for reading and Sorry for the poor English.

CascadeClassifier cascade;
vector faces;

```
String path("d:\\down\\pro\\*.jpg");
vector<String> str;

int index = 0;
char buf[256];

glob(path, str, true);

cout << "load number:" << str.size() << endl;

if (str.size() == 0)
    cout << "no image\n" << endl;

for (int cnt = 0; cnt < str.size(); cnt++) {

    p_img = imread(str[cnt]);

    if (0 == cascade.load(classifier))
    {
        cout << "Error CascadeClassifier load" << endl;
        exit(0);
    }

    cascade.detectMultiScale(p_img, faces, 1.2, 3, 0 | CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30));


    for (size_t i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++)
    {
        rectangle(p_img, faces[i], Scalar(255, 255, 255), 2, 8, 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is my understanding that `faces` is an array containing the faces found by the classifier. What if you just check the length of this array ? If `faces.size()==0` then..